# Dropbox chooser link not being sent to server upon form submit

Tags: forms, post, dropbox, pug

When the form is submitted the value for the dropbox chooser is an empty string on the server. All the other inputs' values show fine on the server. Also, when the success event is fired for the Dropbox chooser the correct link appears on the `alert`.

Why is the link not reaching the backend?

Here is my client code in Jade:

```
extends layout

block styles
block content
    .container
        div#alertStage
        form#shareForm.form-horizontal(method='post', action='/share', enctype='multipart/form-data')
            .control-group
                input(type='text', placeholder='enter class code', name='classCode', required='required')
            .control-group
                input(type='text', placeholder='enter professor', name='professor', required='required')
            .control-group
                textarea(rows='3', placeholder='enter description', name='description', required='required')
            .control-group
                input#db-chooser(type='dropbox-chooser', name='dropboxLink', style='visibility: hidden', data-link-type='preview')
            .control-group
                input#shareSubmit.btn-primary(type='submit', value='Upload')
block scripts
    script(src='https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/1/dropbox.js', id='dropboxjs', data-app-key='kkobu9cjygmh6js')
    script
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#shareSubmit').on('click', function(e)
            {
                var message = '';
                e.preventDefault();
                //TODO: Validate data
                $('#shareForm').submit();
            });
            document.getElementById("db-chooser").addEventListener("DbxChooserSuccess", function(e) 
            {
                alert("Here's the chosen file: " + e.files[0].link)
            }, false);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reported this issue as a bug and it is now resolved.